# Cannot install Azure Functions Extension

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions

I have visual studio 2017 v2 and am trying to install the Azure functions extension. I have tried on a fresh vs install on a fresh PC as well as an older one. Each time I get the error message 'The extension cannot be installed to this product due to prerequisites that cannot be resolved'. It doesn't tell me what they are or what I can do to resolve the problem. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last I checked (a couple of weeks ago) the Azure functions extensions/tooling is only available with VS2017 preview.

You can install it alongside your other stable VS2017 install - see the [azure functions blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/).

Comment: @johnstaveley - Yes, make sure that the version installed is VS2017 v15.3 as mentioned in the blog.

Comment: If only the message in visual studio was more descriptive about what the problem was!

Comment: As long as it is a Visual Studio 2017 Preview version (I just installed version 15.8.0 Preview 1.1 on 5/21/2018), it looks like you'll be fine.